# Accessing the window object using Google Earth Engine code editor

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is it possible to do something like this in Google Earth Engine code editor?

```
location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location.href="someurl";
```

or is there any way I can reload the browser by accessing the window object inside GEE code editor?

I am using the JS API.

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: ok have edited my question, now its only one question